# C - Trouble with simple modulus table, it isn't so simple

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, modulus

I've been crunching through Kernighan and Ritchie "The C Programming Language" and read that `x mod y == x & y-1`. So, I worked it out with pencil and paper, and worked fine, so then I tried to test it and here is the problem:

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  int i, j;

  for(i = 1; i < 10; i++){
    for(j = 1; j < 10; j++)
      printf("%3d",i & j-1);
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Gives the output:

```
  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0
  0  0  2  2  0  0  2  2  0
  0  1  2  3  0  1  2  3  0
  0  0  0  0  4  4  4  4  0
  0  1  0  1  4  5  4  5  0
  0  0  2  2  4  4  6  6  0
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8
  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  8
```

and

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  int i, j;

  for(i = 1; i < 10; i++){
    for(j = 1; j < 10; j++)
      printf("%3d",i % j);
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

gives the output:

```
  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  0  0  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  0  1  0  3  3  3  3  3  3
  0  0  1  0  4  4  4  4  4
  0  1  2  1  0  5  5  5  5
  0  0  0  2  1  0  6  6  6
  0  1  1  3  2  1  0  7  7
  0  0  2  0  3  2  1  0  8
  0  1  0  1  4  3  2  1  0
```

Notice, the only change was the `%` that became `&`.
Any input would be much appreciated

Comment: No, that's not the only change: `i & j-1` => `i % j` (explicitly: `j-1` => `j`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equation

```
x mod y == x & y-1
```

is *only* correct for `y` a power of 2.

If `y = 2^k`, the binary representaion of `y` is one 1-bit followed by `k` 0-bits (and preceded by a number of 0-bits depending on the width of the type), and the representation of `y-1` is `k` 1-bits (preceded by 0s).

Then if you write `x = q*y + r` with `0 <= r < y`, the binary representation of `r` needs at most `k` bits, and the last `k` bits of `q*y` are all 0, so the remainder of `x` modulo `y` consists of the least significant `k` bits of `x`, which are obtained by the bitwise and with `y-1`.

For an odd `y > 1`, `y-1` is even, and so `x & y-1` is always even, hence `(y+1) % y == 1 != (y+1) & (y-1)`. For even `y` not a power of 2, replace 1 with the power of 2 corresponding to the lowest set bit of `y` in `y+1`.

Comment: Thank you, I just realized rows 2, 4 , 8 were congruent.